# How can I call method 'func' from and what is the meaning of implementing this object?

Tags: java, object, anonymous

So I was just playing around with **java 8** and thought of putting { } after creating an object and weirdly it didn't error out.

```
public class Guava{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Guava g = new Guava(){
            int x=1;
            public void func(){
                System.out.println("LOL");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Was expecting the code to error out in line

**`Guava g = new Guava(){ ... };`**

So I want to know if there's a way to actually use the variable 'x' and method 'func' and if this is an actual concept under java that I don't know about? (closures maybe?)

Thanks

Comment: `g.func();` will call `func()`. You are creating an anonymous sub-class of `Guava`. `x` isn't visible outside that sub-class.

Comment: as @ElliottFrisch said this is an anonymous sub class, this is a nice way for creating small classes without opening a new file for them. You can also implement anonymous functions in the same way, look for "Lambda Expressions".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch g.func(); in main() leads to the error 'Cannot resolve method func()' .

Comment: @EladAharon Yes I have understanding of Lambda Expressions and functional programming but 'Anonymous subclasses is a new concept for me' :-)

Comment: Add `func()` to `Guava`. What is `Guava`?

Answer (score 0):

`Guava g = new Guava(){ ... };` creates an [anonymous inner-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

It is an inner class without a name and for which only a single object is created.

In your example, the inner class inherits from `Guava`.